# Parameter estimation for Gaussian of which mean depends on time

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

I have the following model:

$$P(x;t,\theta,\sigma) = N(\mu(t;\theta), \sigma)$$
$$\mu(t) = f(t;\theta)$$

where $N(\mu, \sigma)$ is Normal distribution.

Is it possible to estimate the parameter $\theta$ and $\sigma$ with the data $\{(x, t)_i\}$?

More Specifically, I'd like to estimate $[a,b,c,d,e]$ and $\sigma$ under:

$$\mu(t) = a * r_1(t) * r_2(t)$$

where
$$r_1(t) = R(-R(0, -b(t-c)) + 1)$$
$$r_2(t) = R(-R(0, d(t-e)) + 1)$$
$$R(t) = max(0,t)$$

The shape of this $\mu(t)$ is like the following.

[image]

I don't care the criteria. However, for example, maximum likelihood is fine.

Comment: Btw, as a comment: the bottleneck in here is your $\mu$ function that is complicated and is prone to return all zeros. Are you sure you need this exact function? It probably could be simplified (or approximated) for one that is much simpler to optimize. This is a question that you have to ask yourself looking at the data that you have.

Comment: @Tim Sorry, I've updated $\mu$ function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mu$ depends *only* on time and is not dependent on previous observations and the variance is constant over time, then you have a simple linear regression model

$$ y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \varepsilon_t $$

assuming that relation between $y_t$  and $t$ is linear. If it is not linear, then you can use nonlinear model in form

$$ y_t = g(t; \theta) + \varepsilon_t $$

where $g$ is some nonlinear function, such model can be  estimated e.g. by [non-linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares) (see e.g. [`nls` function in R](https://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendix/Appendix-Nonlinear-Regression.pdf)).

However if it is dependent on previous observations, you would be rather interested in [autoregressive model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model) or other time-series analysis models. Also when variance is changing over time such linear or nonlinear models not accounting for it would be incorrect.

Comment: This is assuming $\mu$ depends linearly on time, while the question specifies a (non-linear) parametrized functional form of $\mu(t)$.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala right, good point, corrected.

Comment: @Tim Thank you! Is it possible to estimate $\sigma$ by nls (or hopefully python's scipy.optimize)? I guess $\sigma$ is the variance of residual. Is it correct?

Comment: @rkjt50r983 if you use [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) or [non-linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares) regression than you just fit a line or curve using least squares and $\sigma^2$ is just a variance of residuals. On another hand, if you maximized Gaussian likelihood function using some optimizer, than $\sigma^2$ would be another parameter to estimate.